# Clout kit basics - what is held on the app vs cloud? (struct instances, specifically)

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

So I'm looking to create a niche market static yelp-style wine/dine restaurant finder.  After asking around, I was suggested to look into cloud kit since apple provides asset storage and synchronization.  I'm looking to provide misc. information in regards to restaurants: menu, location, open times, images; this information will be provided by myself.

With that in mind... here is the problem.  It appears that cloud kit may be the perfect fit, unfortunately beginner-type tutorials are insufficient in explanation or outdated (obj-c - I only know swift).  So for one, would you be able to recommend any tutorials?

Nonetheless, here is the meat of the question...

I am aware that a public database held in a container will be able to hold numerous bits of information: strings, integers, assets, date, etc.
However, would cloud kit (as in, off the device), hold the entirety of instances of a struct in the cloud or are only variables held?  In other words, what is held on the device and what is held in the cloud when using cloud kit?

Also, should I create a iCloud id just for development usage or should I use my existing iCloud if?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/33/overview

Answer (score 2):

Jon,
There is a lot of questions here.
1. CloudKit is very easy to get started, but a little bit of a challenge to use in a real app.
2. You can store basic types + assets in cloud kit; an asset being an image for example or just a glob of data.
3. The https://www.raywenderlich.com/video-tutorials#cloudkit website has a number of good tutorials on the subject in SWIFT, although no its not free, you need to pay a small monthly charge; although its worth it if you want to learn more about code development.